# Как вернуться к началу метода?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

    public static boolean check(String bet) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{1,9}$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(bet);
        return m.matches();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Введите число");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String bet = scanner.nextLine();

        if (check(bet)) {
        выполняется код 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Некорректный ввод, попробуйте снова");
        }
    }
}
```

Только учусь. Подскажите, можно ли в `else` прописать код, который автоматом отсылает на начало, и ты действительно без перезапуска пробуешь снова?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вашу задумку можно реализовать с помощью циклов (например, с помощью `do-while`):

```
boolean isCorrect;

do {
    System.out.println("Введите число");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String bet = scanner.nextLine();
    isCorrect = check(bet);
} while (!isCorrect);


// Код, который должен выполняться при корректном вводе
```

Answer (score 4):

Оберните все то, что у вас в методе `main` в отдельный метод, возвращающий `boolean`, после чего напишите в `main`:

```
while(!ваш_метод()) {}
```

Этот цикл будет работать до тех пор, пока ваш метод не вернет `true`, а вернет тру он только в случае корректного ввода. Точнее, вы сами скажете ему вернуть тру, когда нужно

Answer (score 4):

Достаточно ввести одну переменную и использовать ее в условии цикла `do-while`. Например

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean success = false;        

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Введите число");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String bet = scanner.nextLine();

        success = check(bet);

        if ( success ) {
        //выполняется код 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Некорректный ввод, попробуйте снова");
        }
    } while ( !success );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

У меня получилось так:

```
boolean success=false;
int 1 =0;
Scanner 2 = new scanner(system.in);
if(1==5){
success= true
}else{
success=false}
do{
1=(scanner.nextInt());
if(success){
System.out.print("Good");
}else{
System.out.print("Try again");
}

}while(!success);
```

Comment: Это что за эзотерический язык программирования?

Comment: Получилась ерунда - алгоритм нерабочий.