# Как проверить переменную на тип в Java

Tags: java, scanner

Как проверить переменную, вводимую через Scanner, на принадлежность к типу double ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зависит вообще всё от задачи. В самом простом случае можно использовать [hasNextDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble) для считывания

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(sc.hasNextDouble() ? "(double) " + sc.nextDouble() : " тут не double");
```

через [Double.parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double userInput = 0;        
try {
    userInput = Double.parseDouble(sc.next());        
} catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
    System.out.println("тут не double");
}
```

---

В более сложной задаче действовать по-другому. Но это нужно знать более подробно всю суть

Comment: hasNextDouble уже пробовал. Есть вариант Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); Boolean x =(sc.hasNextDouble()); но нужен вариант, чтобы можно было дальше использовать переменную (sc)

Comment: Так а кто мешает? `hasNextDouble` возвращает булеву если значение `double`, но вот непосредственно считать данные используется `nextDouble()`. так что не понимаю в чем затруднения

Comment: проблема грамотно оформить код. Задача была сделать калькулятор  и если юзер вводит не число а буквы или знаки, то программа говорит ввести число, и это число она потом считает с другим(умножает, делит)

Comment: @Программер тебе надо было сразу так описать проблему)) вообще это частый вопрос. и решается он через любой из циклов, с помощью которого организуется бесконечный цикл до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет нужные данные.... посмотри примеры в **[данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581190/191482)** а попробуй использовать поиск на данном сайте **[по метке java и слову Scanner](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+scanner+while)** или **[\[java\] console](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+console)**

Comment: Спасибо большое!